# How to further group object after replaceRoot in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, nodejs-server

```
{
    "169v55": [
      {
        "code": "2001",
        "active": true,
        "delist": false
      }
    ],
    "SLO1019jkf": [
      {
        "code": "MOUNTY2026",
        "active": false,
        "delist": false,
        "createdAt": "2019-12-26T15:36:51.819Z"
      },
      {
        "code": "MOUNTY2027",
        "active": false,
        "delist": false,
        "createdAt": "2019-12-26T16:25:32.437Z"
      },
      {
        "code": "MOUNTY2054",
        "active": false,
        "delist": false,
        "createdAt": "2020-02-17T05:47:28.558Z"
      }
    ]
}
```

Above result I got after replacing newRoot. Here is my Grouping code which given above result

```
{
    $group: group
},
{
    $project: {
      doc: "$doc",
      date: date,
      type: type
    }
},
{
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      locations: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$doc"
        }
      }
    }
},
{
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$locations"
      }
    }
}
```

Now I need to group again with active and delist. So, output I want as below

```
{
  "169v55": {
    active: 1,
    inactive: 2
  },
  "SLO1019jkf": {
    active: 0,
    inactive: 3
  }
}
```

In above `{ active: 1, inactive: 2 }` means count of total `active` and `inactive` document respective array.

Comment: Instead of using `$push` in the `$group`, try using `$sum` and `$cond` to count the items you need.

Comment: can you give one example @Joe

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the actual input documents.  If the output at the top came from this pipeline, two of the documents right before the group stage looked like (I can't tell what `type` used to contain):

```
{
    _id: "169v55",
    doc:{
        "code": "2001",
        "active": true,
        "delist": false
      },
    type: unknown
}
```

and

```
{
    _id: "SLO1019jkf",
    doc:{
        "code": "MOUNTY2026",
        "active": false,
        "delist": false,
        "createdAt": "2019-12-26T15:36:51.819Z"
      },
    type: unknown
}
```

So if you were to group based on the location, you could sum up active and inactive:

```
{$group:{
    _id:"$_id",
    active: {$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:["$active",true]},1,0]}},
    inactive: {$sum:{$cond:[{$eq:["$active",false]},1,0]}}
}}
```

This will give you each location in separate documents with the counts.  If you need them to actually be in a single array, group by null like you did, but push the counts instead of the original doc field:

```
{ k:"$_id", v:{active:"$active",inactive:"$inactive"} }
```

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I was totally struggling with this query.